# Can you use the using keyword in a delegate in C#?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Can you use the using keyword in a delegate?

Comment: Why not. Have you tried?

Comment: Explain [what you're trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/), [what you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), and what happened.

Comment: It was an interview question I had...

Answer (score 0):

you can use ANY reserved keyword by using `@`

example:

```
 delegate void @using();
```

[see the MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)